# Flutter stopped suddenly with error Dart:core is missing

Tags: macos, flutter

My flutter sdk on Android studio suddenly stopped working without any changes made. I am using mac book pro and the error is:

> Required library 'dat:core' is missing.

I have tried downloading new flutter sdk and also update Android studio but still the same problem

I tried the fix using git clean -xfd

did not work ,, here is the flutter doctor log

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Mac OS X 10.14.3 18D109, locale en-OM)
• Flutter version 1.2.1 at /Users/pocketcarage/Desktop/fluttersdk/flutter-3
• Framework revision 8661d8aecd (4 weeks ago), 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
• Engine revision 3757390fa4
• Dart version 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
• Android SDK at /Users/pocketcarage/Library/Android/sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
• Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[!] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices
✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
  Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
  Or install Xcode via the App Store.
  Once installed, run:
    sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
✗ libimobiledevice and ideviceinstaller are not installed. To install with Brew, run:
    brew update
    brew install --HEAD usbmuxd
    brew link usbmuxd
    brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
    brew install ideviceinstaller
✗ ios-deploy not installed. To install:
    brew install ios-deploy
• CocoaPods version 1.5.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin version 33.4.1
• Dart plugin version 182.5215
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[!] Connected device
! No devices available

   ! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
   PocketCarages-MacBook-Pro:pocketcarage_official pocketcarage$   flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Mac OS X 10.14.3 18D109, locale en-OM)
• Flutter version 1.2.1 at /Users/pocketcarage/Desktop/fluttersdk/flutter-3
• Framework revision 8661d8aecd (4 weeks ago), 2019-02-14 19:19:53 -0800
• Engine revision 3757390fa4
• Dart version 2.1.2 (build 2.1.2-dev.0.0 0a7dcf17eb)

 [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
• Android SDK at /Users/pocketcarage/Library/Android/sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
• Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
• Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)
• All Android licenses accepted.

 [!] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices
✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
  Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
  Or install Xcode via the App Store.
  Once installed, run:
    sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
✗ libimobiledevice and ideviceinstaller are not installed. To install with Brew, run:
    brew update
    brew install --HEAD usbmuxd
    brew link usbmuxd
    brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
    brew install ideviceinstaller
✗ ios-deploy not installed. To install:
    brew install ios-deploy
• CocoaPods version 1.5.3

 [✓] Android Studio (version 3.3)
• Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
• Flutter plugin version 33.4.1
• Dart plugin version 182.5215
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1248-b01)

[!] Connected device
! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Comment: Try https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#flutter-installation-corrupted to ensure the Flutter install is not corrupted. Also try `flutter clean` if you get the error at runtime. Please post the full and exact error message.

Comment: still not working after I tried the solution in the link

Comment: `Required library 'dat:core' is missing.` there is a `r` missing (`dart:core`). Is this only a copy-paste error or is this actually what the error message looks like. I would need more information about the error to be able to tell where it comes from.

Comment: the issue of dart is solved I managed to solve it by updating the path inside .package but a new problem arises saying error: Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'. (uri_does_not_exist at [pocketcarage_official] lib/UI/authentication.dart:2)